# How to temporary disable dependencies in Spring Boot's pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security, pom.xml

So, I want to temporary disable spring security dependency, to perform several tasks. In the pom.xml file I have commented it out like this:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--    <dependency>-->
    <!--        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
    <!--        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
    <!--    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, after i comment it out, I refresh maven dependencies, and when i run the app i get several errors in the console like:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'thymeleafViewResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafWebMvcConfiguration$ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'thymeleafViewResolver' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templateEngine' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine]: Factory method 'templateEngine' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafSecurityDialectConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
at com.example.LoginApp.LoginAppApplication.main(LoginAppApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: If that is all you commented out, it should work. The error is not related to the commented-out dependency. Please check that you didn't commentd-out something else.

Comment: You excluded Spring Security but left in the `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` dependency, which triggers Thymeleaf to install the dialect, which fails due to no Spring Security is present.

Comment: Your right it worked Thanks!

Comment: Consider adding the solution as an answer and accept it or delete the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, i just forgot to also disable the dependency: thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5.
After commenting it out too it worked fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).